# Discord python: How can I get all the roles that can access and/or write to a channel?

Tags: discord.py

How can I get all the roles that can access and/or write to a channel? The main problem is that I saw about checking a single member https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=permissions_for.
Thank you in advance for any reply.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want get all members that can *access* the channel, use `channel.members`
[documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=permissions_for#discord.TextChannel.members).

If you want to get all members that can write in the channel, do something like this:

```py
writers = [member for member in channel.members if channel.permissions_for(member).send_messages]
```